# Buttons in vizard

Tags: python, radio-button, vizard

I am developing a GUI in Vizard in which i am using radio buttons to select correct options, but I have a problem that I cannot solve.

In every group of radio buttons the 1st button always appears to be selected, but is actually not selected. The only way to select it is by choosing another button and then choosing the 1st button again.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I would like that in the beginning none of the buttons are selected.

Comment: Is vizard a package of some kind? I've never heard of it before.

Comment: Is a program that uses python to make 3D etc.. check it in    http://www.worldviz.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Vizard but radio buttons probably have a method or another way of deselecting them similar to radiobutton.deselect() method of Tkinter. Have you looked at their documentation?

Also someone have done this trick, may be you should try it:
Create another radio button in that group, let it be selected by default and make it invisible

```
QuestionBox = vizinfo.add("") #Add the vizinfo object
#Create an invisible Radio button to be the default selected one, so that one of the visible ones must be chosen by the user
invisibleRadio = QuestionBox.add(viz.RADIO, 0, "")  
invisibleRadio.visible(0) #invisible
```

source: http://forum.worldviz.com/showthread.php?t=1611